# UFT8 decoding by saving a file

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I searched a lot and didn't find the solution.

Here is my code:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dicpart"
                                                 ofType:@"rtf"];

NSError *error = nil;
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if (error) NSLog(@"error: %@", error);

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/file.txt", documentsDirectory];

[content writeToFile:fileName
             atomically:NO
               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                  error:&error];

if (error) NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
```

What I'm doing:

1. Get the file (http://take.ms/Xo3Cx, it contains Cyrillic and some special latin symbols)
2. Read the string from this
3. Save the file back immediately with no modification

Problem:

Cyrillic and special latin symbols become to be a rubbish.

I suppose I should do sort of decoding in order to get real symbols in the result file. What should I do to achieve this?

Comment: Please include the actual text you are reading and trying to save; an image of it is useless.

Comment: You're reading an RTF file and saving it to a .txt file, where it will be interpreted as plain text. Save it as a .rtf file and it should be fine. The only difference will be in how subsequent readers interpret it.

Comment: Is this file encoded in UTF8, or is it some other encoding? (Almost certainly it's in some other encoding, which is why it's failing.) For example, KOI8-R or Windows-1251 would likely be readable as UTF8 (i.e. not cause errors), but would trash your Cyrillic.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by changing the unput file format to `.txt`.